# C++: Statically initialize container with data from other statically initialized container

Tags: c++, std, c++20

Is there a way to map keys/values of one statically initialized container to other statically initializing one? Something like that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

const set< pair< string, int > > my_set = {
    ( "three" , 3  ),
    ( "seven" , 7  ),
    ( "twelve", 12 )
};

//how to statically extract pairs' first values?
const set< string > my_strings = my_set.values().map( []( const auto & pair ){ return pair.first; } );

int main() {
    cout << "statically initialized set:" << endl;
    for ( const auto & v : my_strings )
        cout << "    " << v << endl;
}
```

Expecting output:

```
statically initialized set:
    three
    seven
    twelve
```

Comment: The thing you have to be most careful about is if the static data is inside different translation units. The current answers assume the data is ordered in the same file like your questions asks, and you would get different answers if that assumption were removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no need for special library or `c++20`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

const set< pair< string, int > > my_set = {
    { "three" , 3  },
    { "seven" , 7  },
    { "twelve", 12 }
};

//how to statically extract pairs' first values?
const set< string > my_strings = []{
    set<string> data;
    for(auto& pair: my_set){ // or with c++20 : ranges & use set's InputIt constructor
        data.insert(pair.first);
    }
    return data;
}();

int main() {
    cout << "statically initialized set:" << endl;
    for ( const auto & v : my_strings )
        cout << "    " << v << endl;
}
```

---

Note that `std::set` has no constexpr constructor, it would not do compile-time initialization.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Is `my_strings` initialized statically in this case? What `set<> ... = []{}();` construct means? Where can I read about it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Slaus I'm not sure what you mean by `statically`, yes it would initialize correctly and you cannot modify it, but since `std::set` has no `constexpr` constructor, it would not be initialized at compile time (i.e. both `my_set` and `my_strings` are constructed at runtime)

Comment: Thank for answering. Yes, I was wondering if initialization would happen at compile time or not. So I guess it initialized right before `main()` starts executing ...

Comment: @Slaus and the `[]{}();` is an instantly invoked lambda function (I didn't notice I haven't send this message :P )

Comment: @appleapple more common name for this idiom is IIFE:   Immediately-invoked function expression

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl I meant to avoid IIFE (and only describe what it does) since I think that name is javascript-only. (as `function expression`)

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl and yes the `instantly invoked` comes from IIFE, I was also thinking whether it's a good description in `c++` ( good enough? maybe :P )

Comment: @appleapple it is not an official name, but it has been used by Jason Turner wrt C++

Answer (score 4):

With range-v3:

```cpp
const set< string > my_strings =
    my_set 
    | ranges::views::keys
    | ranges::to<std::set>();
```

`views::keys` is in C++20 but `ranges::to` is not.

Comment: For completeness, can you point out the part of the standard that guarantees `my_set` being constructed before `my_strings` ?

Comment: @Jeffrey http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.dynamic

Comment: @Barry this is valid only for stuff in the same TU, right? Otherwise SIOF?

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl Yes, but the question is about the same TU.